# Bounded S-curve from [0; xMax] to [0;1]

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, curves

The generalised logistic function looks like a good start, but how can I introduce finite bounds on the x-axis for the curve to span within ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function

My use-case is the plotting of curves with D3.js for a sustainable finance project where I display a company's board of directors characteristics: e.g. gender diversity, independence, tenure, dissent rate, average age, etc... Each characteristic would be represented by a point on a specific curve, so as to explain to my users what makes a good score or not for each. 
On my Y-axis I'll have a Red-Yellow-Green color band mapping to a function output in [0;1], while the input/x-axis would depend on each characteristic. For board independence, an S-curve would be a good fit, but I can't figure out a suitable equation for my graphics needs...

Comment: Still of interest :)